# Apply generic tranformation to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there easy way to apply generic transformation to numpy array?

like **FOR EXAMPLE** this transposition

```
def T(x,y):
    return (y, x) # just an example

ar = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
])

ar.transform(T)

ar == np.array([
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3, 3],
    [4, 4, 4, 4],
])
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_(function)

Comment: What are you expecting this to do exactly? Transpose? I don't understand your question.

Comment: apply generic transformation given by function T, transposition is just an example

Comment: In `T`, what's `x` and `y`?  scalars?  arrays? indices? What the properties of `ar`?  shape? dtype?  You can't readily add a method to the `ar` class (`ndarray`), but you can define a function that takes an array, and returns another.

Comment: Something like `def transform(data, func): return func(data)`?

Comment: @NilsWerner I've sent you article about what transformation is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_(function) Doubt it will help in your case

Comment: @NilsWerner `data[T(x)] == data.transform(T)[x]`

Comment: Eh? That does not make much sense, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform.html) is what you need

```
def T(p):
    return (p[1], p[0]) # just an example

ar = numpy.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
])

ar = scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform(ar,T)

ar == numpy.array([
   [1, 1, 1, 1],
   [2, 2, 2, 2],
   [3, 3, 3, 3],
   [4, 4, 4, 4]
])
```

Comment: thx, `scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform` is exactly what I need

Answer (score -3):

You are adding an unnecessary extra step. You can just call your function `T` with the array as: `T(ar)`. There is no array-method that you can call on a whole array, since you would just pass the array as an argument to another function instead.

If you wanted to do a general **element-wise** function, see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: What do you mean his example works fine? What is `transform` referring to? It's not an attribute of a numpy array